# React Native - how to pass array map data to other screen

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Good day! I made a array map to display a specific data from my **API**, and I did it successfully. But my next task is to **PASS THOSE DATA FROM API TO OTHER SCREEN.**

> Now, my problem is those data is displayed using **ARRAY MAP** and I
>   have no idea how will I pass my data to other screen.
>
> -- I tried using navigation navigate but it only passes 1 data, what I need is to pass all my data displayed.

Here's my code

```
export default class Category extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            ....
            CHECKED_Data: [],
        };
    }

    fetch_CHECKED_Data = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.***:****/checked/get_All_Cheked/" + this.state.Checked_ORDER_NO );
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ CHECKED_Data: json });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetch_CHECKED_Data();
    }

    For_table_No() {
        return this.state.CHECKED_Data.map((data) => {
            return (
                <View>
                    <View key={key}>
                        <Text>Merged Table: { data.Checked }</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        })
    }

paxFunc(item) {
    if( pax_no > this.state.ForSum_Checked_Capacity ) {
        this.setState({
            MERGE_modal: true
        });
    } else{
        return this.state.CHECKED_Data.map((data) => {
                var Take = this.state.TakeOut;
                if(Take == this.state.TakeOut) {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Dishes', {
                        .....
                        check                   : this.state.check,
                        Checked_ORDER_NO        : this.state.Checked_ORDER_NO,
                        CHECKED                 : data.Checked
                    });
                }
        });
    }
}

render() {
     return(
          .....
               <View>
                    { this.For_table_No() }
               </View>
          ......
     )
}
```

First Screen:

[image]

Second Screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Dishes',this.state.CHECKED_Data)
```

then map the data in that screen exactly like what you have done here

Answer (score 0):

-> Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter.

this.props.navigation.navigate('Dishes',{dataToRender: 
 this.state.CHECKED_Data});

-> In the next page you can access data as

this.props.navigation.state.params.dataToRender;

-> after that in the next page you can setState and perform the required
operation.

for more details, you can go through this link

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Answer (score 0):

After reading my code for half an hour, I found that the cause of the error--or let's just that why it is not passing is because of a "key".

I forgot to declare a key in my other page, that is why my data is not displaying.